# JSONPath expression to look inside different keys

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a JSON returned by a RESTful API:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1484763",
        "name": "Name",
        "values": {
            "0": {
                "value": "Peter"
            }
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2584763",
        "name": "phone",
        "values": {
            "0": {
                "value": "45456456"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I write a JSONPath that extracts a phone number value? (so in this case, "45456456"). What makes the problem harder, phone number object is not always inside "1" key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JsonPath which results in phone number `45456456`

```
$..[?(@.name = 'phone')].values.0.value
```

Basically, you have to apply a filter `?()` where `name  == 'phone'` and then use normal json path.

Try the expression in this [link](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com)

JsonPath expression syntax can be found [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).